# How can I debug my Safari App Extension when I load it from electron?

Tags: macos, electron, safari-app-extension

I have an Electron App that loads a Safari App Extension in the Safari Browser.
When I open the browser, I can see my extension listed in `Safari -> Preferences... -> Extensions`.
As soon as I enable it, I see the Toolbar Icon appear then disappear.
Is there a way for me to debug my extension when it is loaded from Electron?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that we can find crash logs on a Mac machine in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/